# Drupal 6 module install file not creating tables in database with Different table name

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm using the following code to create a database schema using the `.install` file in drupal-6

```
function myModule_install() {
  // Create tables.
  drupal_install_schema('table_name');

}
```

Let's say, the `myModule = 'abc' & table_name = 'sim_table'`; this is working good with the same table name as the module name but my requirement is different then that: I need to create a table name with a different prefix, like "drupal_sim_table", so I am using this code instead
`drupal_install_schema('sim_table');`

but it's not working at all. The module gets installed but tables are not created. I have been trying so many times without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

```
function mymodule_schema() {
  $schema = array();
  $schema['my_table_name'] = array(
  );
  return $schema;
}

function mymodule_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('mymodule');
}
```

which means, in `drupal_install_schema()` you use your module name, but then in `hook_schema()` in `$schema` definition you can use whatever table name you want.